# openjpa throws optimisticklockexception

Tags: jpa, openjpa, optimistic-locking

I am trying openjpa and jpa. All I have is one entity class as corresponding table in the database. one of the attributes of the entity is username and corresponding row in the db table has varchar2(20). and in my main method what i tried to persist and instance of the entity with username longer than 20.
All I am doing is

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(entity); //entity here is the instance with the username longer than 20
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I tried this, hoping to get some other kind of exception, but I don't why I am getting optimisticklockexception.

I do not have any locking setting. I mean I am using default values for locking property.

Does anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: How about you post the entire stack trace and your Entity? What version of OpenJPA? How are you enhancing your Entities?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens...I have noticed that the OptimisticLockException can be thrown in weird cases...

Adding a version field to your table and entity can often make OpenJPA work better with locking...

In your entity bean add this (also add the column named VERSION to your table):

```
private Long version;
@Version
@Column(name="VERSION") 
public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: No, it didn't work. I tried that, if I use correct data it works perfectly. Suppose, if persist a new instance it works well and the version is set to 1. Next, if retrieve the row and make some changes, again it works well and the version is automatically incremented to 2.

Comment: Sorry, hit the enter by mistake. And, when try to persist and instance with invalid data (e.g. field with value, String, with characters more than 20), again it's throwing the same OptimisticLockException. I was thinking, an exception more appropriate would me helpful.